# Is $P/Z(P)$ cyclic when $Z(P)$ is not trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

I'm working my way through a proof given in Dummit and Foote.

> **Theorem:** If $|P| = p^2$ for some prime $p$, then $P$ is abelian.
>
> **Proof:** Since $Z(P)\not = 1$, it follows that $P/Z(P)$ is cyclic $\dots$

Im stuck at the very first line of the proof. I understand why $Z(P)$ isn't trivial (it follows from the class equation that $p\vert|Z(P)|$ so $|Z(P)|\not = 1$). However, I can't understand why that implies $P/Z(P)$ is cyclic.

Im not asking for a whole proof. I just want a few guidelines on how to show that $P/Z(P)$ is cyclic and I'll prove the rest myself.

Comment: What do you know about the order of $P/Z(P)$?

Comment: Do you know a case where you can tell that a group has to be cyclic just given its order?

Comment: Oh, I got it. Since $P/Z(P)$ has order $1$ or $p$, it is either trivially cyclic, or cyclic because any non-identity element acts as a generator, respectively. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you know $Z(P)$ is not trivial, you will see that $P/Z(P)$ is of order $p$ or $1$. Then use Lagrange theorem to see that $P/Z(P)$ is cyclic.